# Issue in using Where Clause in SQOOP

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to use --where option to get conditional data by joining orders table with order_items table using below command :

---

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username retail_dba \
--password cloudera \
--query "Select * from orders o join order_items oi on o.order_id = oi.order_item_order_id where  \$CONDITIONS " \
--where "order_id between 10840 and 10850" \
--target-dir /user/cloudera/order_join_conditional \
--split-by order_id
```

---

Now i don't know whats wrong with this because when i Run same Query in MySQL i get 41 records which is correct But when i run this command in sqoop it will Dump all the 172198 records. I don't understand whats happening and whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a parallel import, Sqoop will use the value of the parameter specified in `--split-by` to substitute the `$CONDITIONS` parameter and generate different queries (which will be executed by different mappers). For instance, Sqoop will first try to find the minimum and maximum value of `order_id` and depending on the number of mappers, will try to execute your query against different subsets of the whole range of possible values of `order_id`.

That way, your query would be translated internally to different parallel queries like these ones:

```
SELECT * FROM orders o join order_items oi on o.order_id = oi.order_item_order_id
 WHERE (order_id >=0 AND order_id < 10000)

SELECT * FROM orders o join order_items oi on o.order_id = oi.order_item_order_id
 WHERE (order_id >=1000 AND order_id < 20000)

...
```

So in this case, the `--where` clause you specified separately will not be used and you'll end up having all the records. But in your particular case, you don't really need the `--split-by` flag, because you are only interested in a particular (and very limited) range of values. So you could use this instead:

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username retail_dba \
--password cloudera \
--query "Select * from orders o join order_items oi on o.order_id = oi.order_item_order_id WHERE (order_id BETWEEN 10840 AND 10850)" \
--target-dir /user/cloudera/order_join_conditional \
-m 1
```

Note also the `-m 1` at the end which (as pointed out by dev ツ) stands for   `--num-mappers` and allows you to tell Sqoop that you want to use just one mapper for your import process (therefore, no parallelism).

If the range of values was bigger, you could use the `--split-by` and use your `where` condition in your free-form query, making use of the parallelism:

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username retail_dba \
--password cloudera \
--query "Select * from orders o join order_items oi on o.order_id = oi.order_item_order_id WHERE (order_id BETWEEN 10840 AND 10850) AND \$CONDITIONS" \
--target-dir /user/cloudera/order_join_conditional \
--split-by order_id
```

Comment: Jamie you forgot `-m 1` in the first query