# Apache Sqoop Where clause not working while using SQOOP IMPORT

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Can anyone tell me what will be the output of this command :
Here departments table was having the default 6 rows (from dept_id 2 to 7) then i added 2 new records to Mysql db ‘retail_db.departments’ table (department_id 8 & 9). What i am trying to do is selecting only the newly added records by using the –where argument & appending (–append) it to the existing HDFS directory for departments.
So when i ran the below command it created a new part-m-000006 file (earlier the default 6 records were splitted into part-m-00000 to part-m-00005 files) and all the records from department_id 2 to 9 (which includes 2 newly added recs) were added to it and as you can see the output below there is repetition of records.

Don’t understand why it is not respecting the where clause:

```
sqoop import \
–connect “jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db” \
–username retail_dba \
–password cloudera \
–query “Select * from departments where \$CONDITIONS” \
–where “department_id > 7” \
–append \
-m 1 \
–target-dir /user/cloudera/sqoop_import/departments

Output :
—————————————————————————————————————————–
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/cloudera/sqoop_import/departments/part*
2,Fitness
3,Footwear
4,Apparel
5,Golf
6,Outdoors
7,Fan Shop
2,Fitness
3,Footwear
4,Apparel
5,Golf
6,Outdoors
7,Fan Shop
8,Sports
9,Jewellery
```

—————————————————————————————————————————–

```
LOGS GENERATED :
—————————————————————————————————————————–
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
16/10/23 12:23:30 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5-cdh5.4.0
16/10/23 12:23:30 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/10/23 12:23:31 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
16/10/23 12:23:31 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/10/23 12:23:31 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: Select * from departments where (1 = 0)
16/10/23 12:23:31 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: Select * from departments where (1 = 0)
16/10/23 12:23:31 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: Select * from departments where (1 = 0)
16/10/23 12:23:31 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/b704a6e6d921fb544ba25c6343b18a36/QueryResult.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
16/10/23 12:23:33 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/b704a6e6d921fb544ba25c6343b18a36/QueryResult.jar
16/10/23 12:23:33 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning query import.
16/10/23 12:23:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
16/10/23 12:23:35 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
16/10/23 12:23:36 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032
16/10/23 12:23:38 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
16/10/23 12:23:38 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/10/23 12:23:39 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1477192024680_0012
16/10/23 12:23:40 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1477192024680_0012
16/10/23 12:23:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1477192024680_0012/
16/10/23 12:23:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1477192024680_0012
16/10/23 12:23:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1477192024680_0012 running in uber mode : false
16/10/23 12:23:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 0% reduce 0%
16/10/23 12:24:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 100% reduce 0%
16/10/23 12:24:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1477192024680_0012 completed successfully
16/10/23 12:24:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30
```

Comment: you asked similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189605/issue-in-using-where-clause-in-sqoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using both `--query` and `--where`. That's why sqoop is not *respecting* `--where` tag.

### `--query` is a superset of `--where`. It covers WHERE conditions.

That's why in your logs you see:

```
INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: Select * from departments where (1 = 0)
```

Use **any one** of these:

- `--query "select * from departments where department_id > 7 AND \$CONDITIONS"`
- `--where "department_id > 7"`